# I need help with YASnippet and tab width

Tags: emacs, tabs

I'm used to have 4 spaces of Tab width. YASnippets uses 2 spaces in its snippets for instance:

```
<div id="$1">
  $0
</div>
```

I thought this would turn it into 4 spaces:

```
<div id="$1">
   $0
</div>
```

but no luck...

So I also tried:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4) 
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16))
```

but no luck again

Is there another setting that helps in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`(setf yas/indent-line NIL)`

That should prevent yas from re-indenting to the current location and use the indendation built into your template.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`(setq yas-indent-line 'fixed)`